# There is any way to validate app signature in ionic?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

It's been 2 days. I was searching for some clue on app certificate validation library/function in ionic. Like in android I found **SignatureCheck.java** [enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/scottyab/b849701972d57cf9562e) So can we also implement something like this in TypeScript for check app certificate is same or not ?
Any suggestion would be helpful thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same just now and after a bit of searching I came across this post: https://medium.com/@atifhussain.nu21/ssl-pinning-in-ionic-cordova-based-applications-ce993adcc07

That looks like a very viable solution, utilizing a cordova plugin/library 'cordova-plugin-sslcertificatechecker'.

Example code:

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import {
 HttpEvent,
 HttpHandler,
 HttpInterceptor,
 HttpRequest
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { CONFIG_CONSTANTS } from '../../common/constant/app-config';
import { MESSAGE_CONSTANTS } from '../../common/constant/message';
declare var window: any;
@Injectable()
export class RequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
 helperFunction: HelperFunctions;
constructor(private network: Network, private injector: Injector) { }
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
this.helperFunction = this.injector.get(HelperFunctions);
let setHeader = {
   'ContentType': 'application/json',
   'Accept': 'application/json',
   'DEVICETYPE': 'MOBILE',
   'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   'dataType': 'json'
  };
let Host = CONFIG_CONSTANTS.BASE_URL;
if (this.network.type === 'none') {
   this.helperFunction.showAlert(MESSAGE_CONSTANTS.CONNECTION_NOT_WORKING);
   return next.handle(request);
  }
return this.checkSecurity(`${Host}${request.url}`, request).flatMap((modifiedReq) => {
   let newReq = null;
   if (modifiedReq['message'] === 'CONNECTION_SECURE') {
    newReq = request.clone({
     url: `${Host}${request.url}`,
     setHeaders: setHeader
    });
   }
   return next.handle(newReq);
  });
 }
checkSecurity(URL, request) {
  return new Observable((observer) => {
   window.plugins.sslCertificateChecker.check(
    (message) => {
     return observer.next({req: request, message: message});
    },
    (message) => {
     return observer.error({req: request, message: message});
    },
    URL,
    CONFIG_CONSTANTS.FINGERPRINT);
  });
 }
}
```

I have yet to try this out myself for my own project. I hope this helps, let us know. :)